# When discovery returns a list of end points, is it consistently ordered

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Support there are 5 servers to discover, S1, S2.., S5. And there are 2 clients, launching discovery, C1 and C2. When the discovery is complete (suppose successfully), will two lists of discovered proxies on C1 and C2 ordered the same?

To that extent, if C1 re-launches discovery, will its new list match the original one as by content as by order?

UPDATE: asked to provide code and I dug into library we use and found this callback. This made me think that it's actually all about what it does, not anything else.

```
    discoveryClient.FindProgressChanged += new EventHandler<FindProgressChangedEventArgs>(ClientFindProgressChanged);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to perform the discovery process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [Ad-hoc or Managed mode?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx)  In Ad-Hoc mode, I don't see how any order can be guaranteed.  In Managed mode... maybe.

Add a Linq query to the result of the discovery if order is important.